# SQL Server goto the next line the cursor came from

Tags: sql-server, goto

I need to go back from the line where the cursor was sent from with goto. The aim is to use part printresult multiple times from the stored procedure

```
declare @a int, @b int

set @a = 1
set @b = 1

nextb:
    goto printresult
    set @b = @b + 1
    if @b < 10 goto nextb

lessb:
    goto printresult
    set @b = @b - 1
    if @b > 1 goto nextb
    goto finish

printresult:    
    select @a, @b 
    --goto ? need to go back the next line where the cursor was sent from

finish:
    select 'finish'
```

Comment: Hi, if i understand your query and your excepted result you can convert your code (printresult) to a sub stored procedure. I'm  going to share a answer with this relevant code.

Comment: Seems like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1602038

Comment: Yes, like a sub stored procedure which should be executed multiple times. Create a separate stored procedure for this goal is also an option. however I tried to solve this within the same procedure. Thank for your kind help.

Comment: @JamesOnedin have you find what your excepted ?

Comment: @PascalSanchez, sub procedure worked fine, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you are loking for the relevant code can help you :

```
/*** Effacement: ********************************************************
IF EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM sysobjects
            WHERE type = 'V' AND name = 'procPrintresult' )
    DROP PROCEDURE procPrintresult
*** Effacement: ********************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE procPrintresult 
    @a int, @b int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT  @a AS 'A', @b AS 'B'

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO


/*** Effacement: ********************************************************
IF EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM sysobjects
            WHERE type = 'V' AND name = 'procExecutionCodeWanted' )
    DROP PROCEDURE procExecutionCodeWanted
*** Effacement: ********************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE procExecutionCodeWanted 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @a int = 1
    DECLARE @b int = 1

    -- nextb block
    while @b < 10 
    begin
        exec procPrintresult @a, @b
        SET @b = @b +1
    end


    -- lessb block
    while @b > 1
    begin 
        exec procPrintresult @a, @b
        SET @b = @b - 1
    end

    -- finish storedProc
    SELECT  'finish' AS 'Finish'

SET NOCOUNT OFF 
GO


EXEC procExecutionCodeWanted
```

Comment: Sorry, my example above was only an example for the logic. Print result should work like a sub procedure called multiple times.

Comment: Yes if you replace call procprintresult by simple select @a , @b this worked at same